# Elasticsearch snapshot how it works

Tags: elasticsearch

i want to understand how snapshot works in elasticsearch
case1
snapshots are taken every day and snapshots older than 1 month are deleted
I have an index cities and for example there are 3 documents
{ barcelona, ​​madrid, urumqi} and, for example, I deleted the barcelona document from the index, it turns out that if a month passes and the last snapshot in which this index was deleted, then I can no longer recover this document?

case2
I have an elasticsearch cluster and a fairly large number of indexes, the rotation is 3 months, if, for example, a couple of indexes change or all are deleted, then if I restore from a snapshot that was taken 3 months ago, will my cluster be fully restored 3 on months ago data? will snapshot process rewrite all data or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you delete the snapshots that cover an index then you cannot recover any of the data in the index. so no, you cannot recover the document
2. a restore will restore the data from the time the snapshot is taken. which means yes, the full data from 3 months will be what you see